# ASP.NET directory access with Role based Security

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, security

I have an ASP.Net portal like application with multiple roles. I have placed the subpages of that role in its own directory adding a web config with an authorization allowing only that role. I have css and javascript in the root directory that can not get access inside the protected role folders. How can I allow these folders css/js to have access to all roles. Sorry if this is easy question I have searched but I am rather new to ASP.NET

Comment: What do you mean CSS can't get access to the protected folder, styles aren't applied properly to the page?  Have you verified the paths to your css/js files are correct on the page (as the user sees it)?

Comment: yes, all style rules and scripts are accessible unless you are inside of a protected directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity's sake I would allow public access to your images, js, and css. Even if you set specific permissions anyone who is able to access your subpages will be able to access your content if those subpages are public-facing.

If you are hell-bent on locking down your app use the location tag in web.config to point to the folder whose permissions you want to open up to specific roles.